# Generalized linear-fractional program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Given the generalized linear-fractional program:
$$\text{Minimize}\;\; \max_{i}\Big|\frac{c_i^Tx+d_i}{e_i^Tx+f_i}\Big|$$
$$\hspace{-5mm}\text{Subject to}\;\; e_i^Tx+f_i>0$$

I convert this into the form:
$$\text{Minimize}\;\; t$$
$$\hspace{26mm}\text{Subject to}\;\; 0\leq c_i^Ty_i+d_iz_i\leq t$$
$$\hspace{37mm}e_i^Ty+f_iz_i=1$$
$$\hspace{24mm}z_i>0$$
where $y_i=\frac{x}{e_i^Tx+f_i}$ and $z_i=\frac{1}{e_i^Tx+f_i}$.

All this is for $i=1,...,k$.

Yet when I put this into my solver (SCSSolver with the modeling tool Convex.jl), using actual data given to me in the problem, I get warnings thrown at me about the problem being likely degenerate and something about column pointers not being strictly increasing, none of which I understand.  I can probably go to a different forum to find out what these warnings mean, but is my mathematical approach to the problem correct?

Comment: The right place to ask this question is with the authors or a forum for SCSSolver.

Comment: yes ok but is my conversion correct?

Comment: The error message about "column pointers not being strictly increasing" almost certainly implies an error in your code and the way that you setup data structures before solving the problem.

Comment: @BrianBorchers so you're saying that it's not my formulation of the problem but the way I coded it?

Comment: I haven't checked the formulation of the problem, but the error message points to an issue with the way in which you've setup the data structure.

Comment: FYI, your conversion ignores the absolute value signs. But it must, because it's not quasiconvex with them in place.

Comment: @MichaelGrant doesn't my requirement that the first restriction be greater than or equal to zero take care of the absolute value signs?

Comment: It does indeed! My mistake

Comment: @MichaelGrant but does your statement about the original problem not being quasiconvex with the absolute value signs still hold?

Comment: Actually I was wrong. The problem is quasiconvex even if you don't constrain $c_i^Tx+d_i$ to be positive, as long as $e_i^Tx+f_i>0$. I don't think you can convert it to a linear program in that more general case, but you can solve it by performing bisection over a sequence of feasibility problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, the mathematical approach you've taken is correct, and standard. You've combined two transformations:

- [Transforming a linear fractional program to a linear program, as shown by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming); deducing the transformation is also a problem in some linear programming textbooks (for instance, Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis)
- Converting a $\max$ function objective into a linear program via constraints, which is typically covered explicitly in linear programming textbooks

About the only thing I would change would be to change the $z_{i} > 0$ constraint to $z_{i} \geq 0$. Although the former is pedantically correct, no LP solver will actually implement such a constraint, so the closest realizable constraint is the latter. In the unlikely event that you obtain an optimal solution for which a $z_{i} = 0$, you could probably insert a cut that would exclude it.